# Change the title of a slds button in JS controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, slds

Maybe this has been asked before, but I was not able to find it anywhere. I am trying to change the title of the slds button on click through controller. I am trying to get the current title through javascript, but it says undefined.
This is what I have so far:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{! c.addShow }">Add Show</button>
var filter = (component.find("addShowBtn")).get("v.title");
console.log(filter);
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set `title` attribute on standard HTML `button` tag and that there’s no component declared with the id `addShowBtn`, which is not available and thus you are getting an error.

You should replace the `button` tag with [`lightning:button`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:button/example) and then using an [`aura:id`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm), you can  achieve what you are trying to do, example below.

**Component**

```
<lightning:button aura:id="myBtn" title="Old Title" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" variant="base" label="Base"/>
```

**JS Controller**

```
handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert(component.find("myBtn").get("v.title")); // alerts text Old Title

    var btn = component.find("myBtn"); // get button component
    btn.set("v.title", "New Title"); // set the title

    alert(component.find("myBtn").get("v.title")); // alerts text New Title
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the component.find you need to define the aura:id attribute on your button.

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{! c.addShow }" aura:id="addShowBtn">Add Show</button>
```

Then on your controller you can do the following

```
var filter = (component.find("addShowBtn")).getElement();
filter.innerHTML = "Title changed";
```